# Changing the overall color of different panels using another jFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, background-color

So i am working on a software and I have reached a particular point where in the settings window (separate jFrame from the main), I should be able to change the color of two different panels using a ComboBox(called Color_cb1).
I have used a switch statement to get the selected index and change colors in the other form like so:[the screenshot of the entire code is given here -> Screenshot:

[image]

But it just doesn't seem to change anything! Can someone help out here?

Comment: 1. The settings window should never be a JFrame since it does not represent a new application. 2. Rather it represents a sub-window of the main application and so should be a "dialog" window which for Swing means that you should make it a JDialog. 3. Your question is in a nutshell, "how can I change the state of one object from another object", and the general answer is to call a method on the other object. Your code doesn't work, meaning its doing something wrong, perhaps calling a method on the wrong instance, but there's no way we can tell what the problem is without your posting...

Comment: .... decent pertinent code, preferably a [mcve]. I strongly urge you to create one of these, a new separate program, one that solely tries to do the problem you're trying to solve and nothing more, a program small enough to post in its entirety here with your question, one that compiles and runs for us.

Comment: 4. ***Never*** post code as an image. We can't copy and run this code, we can't modify it, it's useless to us.

Comment: I've edited your question to show your image, to add a Swing tag and to remove the JavaScript tag since your question has nothing to do with this language. Please let me know if you have any questions about the comments above, and note the quicker you can show your  [mcve] likely the quicker and better you'll get a decent answer.

Comment: Please see update to posted code. Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, it's here:

```
Chatroom c = new Chatroom();
```

You then call methods to try to change the state of this object, `c.xxx.someMethod()`; and your methods in fact *work*, they do change the state of `c`, but please understand that your changing the *wrong* object. Your Chatroom object, c, is not the same as the Chatroom that is actually displayed, and changing the state of `c` will have no magical effect on the displayed object. To visualize, imagine that your wife has a car, and it needs gas. Your above solution is similar to your buying a new car of the exact same make, model and year, then filling it with gas, and expecting that now your wife's car has gas. Doesn't work. Instead you need to get a hold of your wife's car, fill *it* with gas, and now things are good.

One possible solution is to make the state fields `static`, and this is a bad solution since it causes the class to lose OOP benefits, to make it tougher to debug, to increase potential complexity and increase the risk of bugs.

A better solution is to pass a *reference* to the visualized Chatroom object into this class, and call your methods on it. Pass the reference in via a constructor or setter parameter, and you'll be able to use it.

For an example of a MCVE that shows use of a JDialog as well as passing a reference of one object into another via a constructor parameter, note the program below. In this program, I have two JPanels, a MainPanel and a DialogPanel, one the main JPanel for the application, the other the JPanel that his held by the JDialog, and when I create the JDialog, I pass the main panel into like so:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    // ....

    // create the dialog, passing the main panel into it:
    private DialogPanel dialogPanel = new DialogPanel(this);
```

Then within the DialogPanel's constructor, I set a field with the parameter:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DialogPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainPanel mainPanel;
    // ....

    public DialogPanel(MainPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
```

and then use this mainPanel field within an ActionListener held by the dialog panel:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ColorPair colorPair = (ColorPair) colorCombo.getSelectedItem();
    mainPanel.setCenterBackground(colorPair.getColor());
    mainPanel.setSideBackground(colorPair.getDarkColor());
}
```

Also, since you're working with Color pairs, I created an enum called `ColorPair` that ties the two colors together with a String:

```
public enum ColorPair {
    BLUE("Blue", new Color(52, 73, 94), new Color(44, 62, 80)), 
    GREEN("Green", new Color(46, 204, 113), new Color(39, 174, 96)), 
    TURQ("Turquoise", new Color(26, 188, 156), new Color(22, 160, 133)), 
    GREY("Grey", new Color(149, 165, 166), new Color(127, 140, 141));

    private ColorPair(String text, Color color1, Color color2) {
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color1;
        this.darkColor = color2;
    }

    private String text;
    private Color color;
    private Color darkColor;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public Color getDarkColor() {
        return darkColor;
    }
}
```

Why do this? Well it helps us create a nifty effect where we render the two colors plus the text in the JComboBox that lets us select colors by using a custom ListCellRenderer class:

```
public class ColorPairRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<ColorPair> {
    private static final int IMG_W = 100;
    private static final int IMG_H = 20;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Map<ColorPair, Icon> iconMap = new EnumMap<>(ColorPair.class);

    public ColorPairRenderer() {
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        for (ColorPair colorPair : ColorPair.values()) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int width = IMG_W / 2;
            int height = IMG_H;
            g.setColor(colorPair.getColor());
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

            x = width;
            g.setColor(colorPair.getDarkColor());
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

            x = 0;
            width = IMG_W;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g.dispose();
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            iconMap.put(colorPair, icon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends ColorPair> list, ColorPair value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value != null) {
            label.setText(value.getText());
            label.setIcon(iconMap.get(value));
        } else {
            label.setText("");
            label.setIcon(null);
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

---

---

To see the whole thing in action, copy and paste the code below into your IDE into class file called ChangeColor.java, and run it (updated to show how easy it is to add new colors -- one line of code):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangeColor {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Change Color");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel();

    // create the dialog, passing the main panel into it:
    private DialogPanel dialogPanel = new DialogPanel(this);
    private JDialog dialog;

    public MainPanel() {
        centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        sidePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 400));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        centerPanel.add(new JButton(new ShowColorDialogAction("Change Colors")));
    }

    public void setCenterBackground(Color c) {
        centerPanel.setBackground(c);
    }

    public void setSideBackground(Color c) {
        sidePanel.setBackground(c);
    }

    private class ShowColorDialogAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ShowColorDialogAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (dialog == null) {                
                Window frame = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MainPanel.this);
                dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Color Setter", ModalityType.MODELESS);
                dialog.getContentPane().add(dialogPanel);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            }
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DialogPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainPanel mainPanel;
    private JComboBox<ColorPair> colorCombo = new JComboBox<>(ColorPair.values());

    public DialogPanel(MainPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
        colorCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        colorCombo.setRenderer(new ColorPairRenderer());
        colorCombo.addActionListener(new ColorComboListener());
        add(colorCombo);
    }

    private class ColorComboListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ColorPair colorPair = (ColorPair) colorCombo.getSelectedItem();
            mainPanel.setCenterBackground(colorPair.getColor());
            mainPanel.setSideBackground(colorPair.getDarkColor());
        }
    }
}

class ColorPairRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<ColorPair> {
    private static final int IMG_W = 100;
    private static final int IMG_H = 20;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Map<ColorPair, Icon> iconMap = new EnumMap<>(ColorPair.class);

    public ColorPairRenderer() {
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        for (ColorPair colorPair : ColorPair.values()) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int width = IMG_W / 2;
            int height = IMG_H;
            g.setColor(colorPair.getColor());
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

            x = width;
            g.setColor(colorPair.getDarkColor());
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

            x = 0;
            width = IMG_W;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g.dispose();
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            iconMap.put(colorPair, icon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends ColorPair> list, ColorPair value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value != null) {
            label.setText(value.getText());
            label.setIcon(iconMap.get(value));
        } else {
            label.setText("");
            label.setIcon(null);
        }

        if (isSelected) {
            label.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        } else {
            label.setBackground(null);
        }
        return label;
    }
}

enum ColorPair {
    BLUE("Blue", new Color(52, 73, 94), new Color(44, 62, 80)), 
    GREEN("Green", new Color(46, 204, 113), new Color(39, 174, 96)),
    TURQ("Turquoise", new Color(26, 188, 156), new Color(22, 160, 133)), 
    RED("Red", new Color(204, 46, 113), new Color(174, 39, 96)),
    YELLOW("Yellow", new Color(204, 204, 46), new Color(174, 174, 39)),
    Violet("Violet", new Color(204, 46, 204), new Color(174, 39, 174)),
    GREY("Grey", new Color(149, 165, 166), new Color(127, 140, 141));

    private ColorPair(String text, Color color1, Color color2) {
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color1;
        this.darkColor = color2;
    }

    private String text;
    private Color color;
    private Color darkColor;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public Color getDarkColor() {
        return darkColor;
    }
}
```